# How to kill previous instances of a particular activity from call stack

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My activity flow is like **A->B->C->B**,

When I press reset button in activity C I go to Activity B

```
Button reset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, B.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

But, I want to destroy the previous instance of activity B when I press reset button in activity C, so that my stack becomes
**[A | C| B]**.
I can't finish Activity B while going to Activity C as I might have to come back to B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when you start B form c it will deleted the unneeded B

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use broadcast finish order and when receive in activity a finish that